# how to get more accuracy on CNN with less number of images

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

currently I am working on flower Classification dataset of kaggle which has only 210 images, with this set of image I am getting accuracy of only 11% on validation set.

```
enter code here

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import cv2
#from tqdm import tqdm
import os
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

flower_img = r'C:\Users\asus\Downloads\flower_images\flower_images'

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\asus\Downloads\flower_images\flower_labels.csv')
img = os.listdir(flower_img)[1]
image_name = [img.split('.')[-2] for img in os.listdir(flower_img)]
label_array = np.array(data['label'])
label_unique = np.unique(label_array)
names = [' phlox','rose','calendula','iris','leucanthemum maximum','bellflower','viola','rudbeckia laciniata','peony','aquilegia']


Flower_names = {}
for i in range(10):
    Flower_names[i] = names[i]
print(Flower_names)
Flower_names.get(8)
x = data['label'][2]
Flower_names.get(x)

i=0
for img in os.listdir(flower_img):
    #print(img)

    path = os.path.join(flower_img,img)
    #img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    #print(img.shape)
    img = cv2.resize(img,(128,128))
    data['file'][i] = np.array(img)
    i+=1
data['file'][0].shape

plt.imshow(data['file'][0])
plt.show()

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Conv2D,Activation,MaxPool2D,Dropout,Flatten

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3,activation='relu',input_shape=(128,128,3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

#model.add(Conv2D(512,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
#model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

from keras.optimizers import Adam
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(lr=0.002),metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

x = np.array([i for i in data['file']]).reshape(-1,128,128,3)
y = np.array([i for i in data['label']])

from keras.utils import to_categorical
y = to_categorical(y)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y)

model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),epochs=10)

model.evaluate(x_test,y_test)

model.evaluate(x_train,y_train)
```

how can I increase accuracy only using this dataset also how can I predict classes for any input image.

Link of Flower color images dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/olgabelitskaya/flower-color-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataset size is very small. Convolutional neural networks are optimal when trained using very large data sets. You really want to have thousands of images (or more!) in your data set.

You can try to enhance your current data set by using various image processing techniques to increase the size of the data set. These techniques will take the original images, skew them, rotate them and do other modification to bolster the size of the training data. These techniques can be helpful, but increasing the natural size of the data set is preferred.

If you cannot increase the size of the dataset, you should examine why you need to use a CNN. There are other algorithms that may give better results when trained with a smaller data set. Take a look at [Support Vector Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine) or [k-NN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm).

If you must use a CNN, [Transfer Learning](https://www.learnopencv.com/keras-tutorial-transfer-learning-using-pre-trained-models/) is a good solution. You can use the features from a trained model and apply them to your problem. I have had great success with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The things you can do:

- Progressive resizing [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/boost-your-cnn-image-classifier-performance-with-progressive-resizing-in-keras-a7d96da06e20)
- Image augmentation [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-configure-image-data-augmentation-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/)
- Transfer learning [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-transfer-learning-for-beginners-6c9b8b7143e)

To be honest, there are much and much more techniques could be utilized to enhance the effectiveness of used data. Try to search about this topic. These ones are the ones that I remember in a minute. These ones that I've given link are just major example ones. You can dig better  with a dedicated research.